# MMRecord: What should KeyPathforResponseObject return for the whole response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking-2

The JSON response which I get from the API will be something like this

```
( 
{
   key11:value11,
   key12:value12,
},
{
   key21:value21,
   key22:value22,
}
)
```

So, when I subclass `MMRecord` and do this

```
+ (NSString *)keyPathForResponseObject {
    return ___;
}
```

What should I return from here, `@""` or `@"default"` or something else?
I searched the documentation, it says

`Default is whatever is returned by this method on the MMRecord subclass.`

What does that mean?

I'm pretty new to iOS. Help me out! I'm using MMRecord-1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (NSString *)keyPathForResponseObject {
    return nil; //To capture the entire response
}
```